# How to do lazy instantiation in python?

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization

in the class below variables with str type are used but without declaring value

```
from abc import ABC

class User(ABC):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
```

is this lazy instantiation?

Comment: No, that's a class attribute type annotation. Nothing is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

This exact example isn't really anything. No attributes are created. If the class were decorated with `@dataclass`, then the decorator would use the annotations to *generate* an `__init__` method for the class that did define the instance attributes. For example,

```
@dataclass
class User(ABC):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str

    # Something like this is added automatically
    # def __init__(self, first_name: str, last_name: str):
    #     self.first_name = first_name
    #     self.last_name = last_name
```

I've never heard the term "lazy instantiation", but it suggests something like this:

1. When you call `u = User("john", "doe")`, the `__init__` method isn't called yet. You get back a "promise" to initialize the object when and if it is necessary.
2. If you try to access `u.first_name`, *then* `__init__` gets executed and a value is assigned to the `first_name` attribute.

---

Lazy *initialization* would be supported through, for example, the use of a property whose getter is responsible for initializing a private attribute on demand. Something like

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None  # "uninitialized" x

    @property
    def x(self):
        if self._x is None:
            self._x = expensive_initialization()
        return self._x

a = A()
```

The first time `a.x` is accessed, the value of `a._x` triggers the call to `expensive_initialization`. Subsequent uses of `a.x` will find `a._x` to be the desired value to return immediately.

Comment: tags suggest it was probably meant to be `lazy initialization`, which is quite common technique.

Answer (score -2):

please refer to this documentation. [https://www.codespeedy.com/lazy-class-instantiation-in-python/#:~:text=It%20is%20achieved%20by%20increasing,first%20use%20to%20the%20caller](https://www.codespeedy.com/lazy-class-instantiation-in-python/#:%7E:text=It%20is%20achieved%20by%20increasing,first%20use%20to%20the%20caller).

Lazy instantiation or Initialization is the skill of delaying an object creation, the calculation of any data or some other process till the first time it is required. In short, it is lazy evaluation specifically referring to the instantiation of either objects or other resources.

So, lazy instantiation makes instantiation work slow and get access only when needed.

Comment: Your last point is incorrect. Lazy instantiation defers instantiation until a point at which the value is required. For example, you may have a class that reads data from a file stores that data, and provides additional functions that do some expensive calculations. Rather than computing those calculations at class initialisation, you may set the computation results only as the methods are called.